# Is it possible to rate and review in the app without open the store in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a screen like below in my application. I want to share the rating and comment given by the user on this screen directly on the stores. When I searched, I saw that most packages open a modal. However, I want the comments and ratings written here to be shared directly in the stores after pressing the "rate" button. Is it possible to do this in React native?

[image]

Comment: No, it's not possible. There's no API for this

Comment: No -- if it were possible to programmatically add your own reviews, people would abuse the system.